# python command not found

Tags: python, git

I am trying to install [python crawler](https://github.com/bianjiang/tweetf0rm) for twitter on Windows 7.

I needed to install python of course, I used Python 34 on the directory `C:/Python34`.

I needed to use a command `git clone .`. Which was unrecognized using the windows command prompt so I had to install MINGW32.

Now I need to use python to run the setup for [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) as explained.
I wrote the following command line : `python setup.py install`
and got the following error :  `python : command not found`

I did some search and tried to add python path as following : 
control panel >> system>> environment variables >> then added 
`C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts`
to the path but it didn't solve the error .

I also tried: `set PYTHONPATH=%C:/Python34%` but with the same error .

How can I use python using MINGW32?

Comment: Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and then install git through the cygwin package manager

Comment: If you've added it to your path, you need to close the command prompt and reopen.

Comment: After you added the environment variable did you open a new terminal window?  At least in the past (I haven't checked for a while) changing the environment variables as you did won't affect already open terminals

Answer (score 2):

It's not `PYTHONPATH` you have to set, but `PATH`.

`PYTHONPATH` tells to python where to find python modules, whereas `PATH` tells to the system where to find binaries (such as python itself).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows environment variables to take effect, you need to restart the command prompt. Logging out and logging in would be the best way to ensure that everything in your environment gets applied correctly.

Comment: thanks , Can somebody help to install python crawler for twitter ?

Comment: I am installing tweetf0rm from the above link and it needs twython ..I installed both using git clone but I am unable to continue ..I can't understand where can i write the next commands ? on python or in git bash ? Can some body suggest a tutorial or something that can help ?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" (make the tick next to the answer green). Please ask a new question for other problems.